# JS para clicar em um botão automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia! Estou com um problema que preciso fazer mais de 1000 alterações em umas páginas web, e queria automatizar isso. Minha ideia foi fazer isso via JS. Pesquisei pela web e achei o exemplo `document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();` mas o botão em questão não tem `ID` e tem uma propriedade que nunca vi (essa `editor-command`). Como posso fazer isso?

```html
<li editor-command="insertoptions">
  <span class="KB_Editor_Bdr_div Insert_Type" orgtitle="Insert options">Insert
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#KBEditortools_block_down_arrow"></use>
    </svg>
  </span>
</li>
```

O botão em questão:

[image: botão]

Comment: `document.querySelector('[editor-command="insertoptions"]')`. Você pode usar esse jeito pra selecionar por atributo, mas não sei se é isso mesmo o que você precisa... O `onclick` está nessa `li`?

Comment: Eu apaguei meus comentários pois com a informação que você me deu eu consegui resolver, muitíssimo obrigado! Você tem algum link onde posso entender como esse querySelector funciona para aprender mais?

Comment: A pergunta acima possui uma resposta com o link para documentação do MDN